# How to return HTTP 500 from ASP.NET Core RC2 Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Back in RC1, I would do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string something)
{    
    try{
        // ...
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

In RC2, there no longer is `HttpStatusCodeResult`, and there is nothing I can find that lets me return a 500 type of IActionResult.

Is the approach now entirely different for what I'm asking? Do we no longer try-catch in `Controller` code? Do we just let the framework throw a generic 500 exception back to the API caller? For development, how can I see the exact exception stack?

Answer (score 398, accepted):

From what I can see there are helper methods inside the `ControllerBase` class. Just use the `StatusCode` method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string something)
{    
    //...
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         LogException(e);
         return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

You may also use the `StatusCode(int statusCode, object value)` overload which also negotiates the content.

Comment: doing this, we lose the CORS headers, so errors are hidden from browser clients. V frustrating.

Comment: @bbsimonbb Internal errors should be hidden from clients. They should be logged  for developers.

Comment: Developers should have, have traditionally enjoyed, the prerogative to choose what level of error information is returned.

Comment: better: return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);

Answer (score 271):

You could use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.StatusCode` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes` to form your response, if you don't wish to hardcode specific numbers.

```
return  StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
```

*UPDATE: Aug 2019*

Perhaps not directly related to the original question but when trying to achieve the same result with `Microsoft Azure Functions` I found that I had to construct a new `StatusCodeResult` object found in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` assembly. My code now looks like this;

```
return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
```

Comment: Great one, avoids any hardcoded parts/"magic numbers". I've used StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) before but I like yours better.

Comment: One thing I didn't consider at the time is that it makes the code more readable, coming back to it you know what error number 500 relates to, it's right there in the code. Self documenting :-)

Comment: I can't imagine internal server error (500) changing anytime soon.

Comment: awesome. this also really cleans up my swagger attributes. ex: [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]

Answer (score 112):

If you need a body in your response, you can call

```
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, responseObject);
```

This will return a 500 with the response object.

Comment: If you don't want to create a specific response object type: `return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { message = "error occurred" });` And of course, you can add as descriptive a message as you like, and other elements as well.

Answer (score 44):

For aspnetcore-3.1, you can also use `Problem()` like below;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
 [Route("/error-local-development")]
public IActionResult ErrorLocalDevelopment(
    [FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
{
    if (webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName != "Development")
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "This shouldn't be invoked in non-development environments.");
    }

    var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

    return Problem(
        detail: context.Error.StackTrace,
        title: context.Error.Message);
}
```

Comment: the same is true for NET5

Answer (score 27):

A better way to handle this as of now (1.1) is to do this in `Startup.cs`'s `Configure()`:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

This will execute the route for `/Error`. This will save you from adding try-catch blocks to every action you write.

Of course, you'll need to add an ErrorController similar to this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling).

---

In case you want to get the actual exception data, you may add this to the above `Get()` right before the `return` statement.

```
// Get the details of the exception that occurred
var exceptionFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

if (exceptionFeature != null)
{
    // Get which route the exception occurred at
    string routeWhereExceptionOccurred = exceptionFeature.Path;

    // Get the exception that occurred
    Exception exceptionThatOccurred = exceptionFeature.Error;

    // TODO: Do something with the exception
    // Log it with Serilog?
    // Send an e-mail, text, fax, or carrier pidgeon?  Maybe all of the above?
    // Whatever you do, be careful to catch any exceptions, otherwise you'll end up with a blank page and throwing a 500
}
```

Above snippet taken from [Scott Sauber's blog](https://scottsauber.com/2017/04/03/adding-global-error-handling-and-logging-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: this is awesome, but how can i log the exception that was thrown?

Comment: @redwards510 Here's how you do it: https://scottsauber.com/2017/04/03/adding-global-error-handling-and-logging-in-asp-net-core/ I'll update my answer to reflect it, since it's a very common use case 

Comment: @gldraphael We are currently using Core 2.1. Scott's blog is great, but I'm curious if using IExceptionHandlerPathFeature is currently the recommended best practices. Perhaps creating custom middleware is better?

Comment: @Pavel we are using the `ExceptionHandler` middleware here. You may, of course, roll your own or extend it as you see fit. Here's the [link to the sources](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/f8e816b5448b6571f57e53d2440005c91be60f59/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler). EDIT: [See this line](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/f8e816b5448b6571f57e53d2440005c91be60f59/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L78) for `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature `.

Answer (score 26):

How about creating a custom ObjectResult class that represents an Internal Server Error like the one for `OkObjectResult`?
You can put a simple method in your own base class so that you can easily generate the InternalServerError and return it just like you do `Ok()` or `BadRequest()`.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : MyControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{key}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int key)
    {
        try
        {
            //do something that fails
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogException(e);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}

public class MyControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    public InternalServerErrorObjectResult InternalServerError()
    {
        return new InternalServerErrorObjectResult();
    }

    public InternalServerErrorObjectResult InternalServerError(object value)
    {
        return new InternalServerErrorObjectResult(value);
    }
}

public class InternalServerErrorObjectResult : ObjectResult
{
    public InternalServerErrorObjectResult(object value) : base(value)
    {
        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
    }

    public InternalServerErrorObjectResult() : this(null)
    {
        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you we have a class library and it has a method  that returns ActionResult so regular solutions to return StatusCode(500) don't work in this case and having a custom ObjectResult is what we needed.

Comment: Amazing this wasn't included in the options but oh well. simple enough. thanks!

Answer (score 22):

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
```

Should be used in non-ASP.NET contexts (see other answers for ASP.NET Core).

`HttpStatusCode` is an enumeration in `System.Net`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following code:

```
return StatusCode(500,"message");
```

Here is a sample code:

```
public Task<IActionResult> GetById(int courseId)
{
  try
  {
     var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetCourse(courseId));
     return Ok(result);
  }
  catch(Exception ex) 
  {
     return StatusCode(500,ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When you want to return a JSON response in MVC .Net Core You can also use:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;//Equals to HTTPResponse 500
return Json(new { responseText = "my error" });
```

This will return both JSON result and HTTPStatus. I use it for returning results to jQuery.ajax().

Comment: I had to use `return new JsonResult ...` but otherwise worked great.

Answer (score 9):

The built-in Problem()-method of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc will return a "problem detail"-response based on RFC 7807 (in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later). **It will always return status-code 500 as long as no other status is explicitly set.**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(
            //all parameters are optional:
            //detail: "Error while processing posted data."; //an explanation, ex.Stacktrace, ...
            //instance: "/city/London"  //A reference that identifies the specific occurrence of the problem
            //title: "An error occured." //a short title, maybe ex.Message
            //statusCode: StatusCodes.Status504GatewayTimeout, //will always return code 500 if not explicitly set
            //type: "http://example.com/errors/error-123-details"  //a reference to more information
            );
    }           
}
```

Without setting any parameters it will return this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",
    "title": "An error occured while processing your request.",
    "status": 500,
    "traceId": "|fadaed95-4d06eb16160e4996."
}
```

More infos about "problem details" parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

For API Responses (using net core), I have tried this and seems that it is working fine:

```
var err = Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, SerializerSettings), "application/x-javascript", contentEncoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
err.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
return err;
```

You just need to create a response object first, then respond this. Doing this, we can retain the content type, encoding, and add a status code as well.

Just adding this for future reference to anybody who is stuck as well and wants a quick and easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-6.0) there is a method named [Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-problem(system-string-system-string-system-nullable((system-int32))-system-string-system-string)) that specifically can handle 500 Errors. It returns Object result with Problem details; such as StatusCode, type, instance, detail.

All you have to do is just call it.

```
return Problem();
```

Comment: To anyone who wonders how to unit test it
see https://stackoverflow.com/q/60740134/9547346

Answer (score 0):

when using an error filter, this would be handy to return a `500` from an ASP.NET API,

```
return new ObjectResult(new { /* any object */ })
{
    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
};
```