# Returning a 404 from an explicitly typed ASP.NET Core API controller (not IActionResult)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-webapi

ASP.NET Core API controllers typically return explicit types (and do so by default if you create a new project), something like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ThingsController : Controller
{
    // GET api/things
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Thing>> GetAsync()
    {
        //...
    }

    // GET api/things/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<Thing> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        Thing thingFromDB = await GetThingFromDBAsync();
        if(thingFromDB == null)
            return null; // This returns HTTP 204

        // Process thingFromDB, blah blah blah
        return thing;
    }

    // POST api/things
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]Thing thing)
    {
        //..
    }

    //... and so on...
}
```

The problem is that `return null;` - it returns an HTTP `204`: success, no content.

This is then regarded by a lot of client side Javascript components as success, so there's code like:

```
const response = await fetch('.../api/things/5', {method: 'GET' ...});
if(response.ok)
    return await response.json(); // Error, no content!
```

A search online (such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793418/how-to-return-http-500-from-asp-net-core-rc2-web-api) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41465343)) points to helpful `return NotFound();` extension methods for the controller, but all these return `IActionResult`, which isn't compatible with my `Task<Thing>` return type. That design pattern looks like this:

```
// GET api/things/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id)
{
    var thingFromDB = await GetThingFromDBAsync();
    if (thingFromDB == null)
        return NotFound();

    // Process thingFromDB, blah blah blah
    return Ok(thing);
}
```

That works, but to use it the return type of `GetAsync` must be changed to `Task<IActionResult>` - the explicit typing is lost, and either all the return types on the controller have to change (i.e. not use explicit typing at all) or there will be a mix where some actions deal with explicit types while others. In addition unit tests now need to make assumptions about the serialisation and explicitly deserialise the content of the `IActionResult` where before they had a concrete type.

There are loads of ways around this, but it appears to be a confusing mishmash that could easily be designed out, so the real question is: **what is the correct way intended by the ASP.NET Core designers?**

It seems that the possible options are:

1. Have a weird (messy to test) mix of explicit types and `IActionResult` depending on expected type.
2. Forget about explicit types, they're not really supported by Core MVC, *always* use `IActionResult` (in which case why are they present at all?)
3. Write an implementation of `HttpResponseException` and use it like `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484262/905) for an implementation). However, that does require using exceptions for program flow, which is generally a bad idea and also [deprecated by the MVC Core team](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4311#issuecomment-198324107).
4. Write an implementation of `HttpNoContentOutputFormatter` that returns `404` for GET requests.
5. Something else I'm missing in how Core MVC is supposed to work?
6. Or is there a reason why `204` is correct and `404` wrong for a failed GET request?

These all involve compromises and refactoring that lose something or add what seems to be unnecessary complexity at odds with the design of MVC Core. Which compromise is the correct one and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return HTTP 500 from ASP.NET Core RC2 Web Api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793418/how-to-return-http-500-from-asp-net-core-rc2-web-api)

Comment: @Hackerman hi, did you read the question? I am specifically aware of `StatusCode(500)` and it only works with actions that return `IActionResult`, which I then go into some detail on.

Comment: It's the same principle....and yes, I read the question

Comment: @Hackerman no, it specifically isn't. That _only_ works with `IActionResult`. I'm asking about actions with _explicit types_. I go on to enquire about the use of `IActionResult` in the first bullet point, but I'm not asking how to call `StatusCode(404)` - I already know and cite it in the question.

Comment: Did you really read the Q&A...did you read all the alternatives that they propose?...I mean did you even try or you just want someone with a full answer...stop complaining, I just post a possible duplicate, I didn't downvote or vote to close your question....jesus

Comment: For your scenario the solution could be something like `return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);` ...also according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting `For non-trivial actions with multiple return types or options (for example, different HTTP status codes based on the result of operations performed), prefer IActionResult as the return type.`

Comment: @Hackerman you voted to close my question as a dupe of a question that I had found, read and gone through _before I asked this question_ and one that I addressed in the question as not the answer I was looking for. Obviously I went on the defensive - I want an answer to _my_ question, not to be pointed back in a circle. Your final comment is actually useful and begins to address what I'm actually asking about - you should flesh it out to a full answer.

Comment: Ok, let me gather a little bit more of info, just to be 100% sure.

Comment: Ok, I got more info on the subject...in order to accomplish something like that(still I think that the best approach should be using `IActionResult`), you can follow this example `public Item Get(int id)
{
    var item = _repo.FindById(id);
    if (item == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    return item;
}
` where you can return an `HttpResponseException` if `thing` is `null`...

Comment: @Hackerman that makes a lot more sense - throw an exception for an error state (though I still have a suspicion that server exceptions should be 5xx statuses, but that might just be my inner coding pedant). It also has the potential to trip any exception logging unnecessarily. I'll give it some testing. Put this in an answer - it's gotten to big for comments.

Comment: done!!...join me on linkedin (it's on my profile)

Comment: I can also add against IActionResult: making return type implicit forces your unit tests to become cumbersome in getting underlying objects.

Comment: @Nickolodeon yeah, see point 1. above.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This is [addressed in ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/02/asp-net-core-2-1-roadmap/) with `ActionResult<T>`:

```
public ActionResult<Thing> Get(int id) {
    Thing thing = GetThingFromDB();

    if (thing == null)
        return NotFound();

    return thing;
}
```

Or even:

```
public ActionResult<Thing> Get(int id) =>
    GetThingFromDB() ?? NotFound();
```

I'll update this answer with more detail once I've implemented it.

### Original Answer

In ASP.NET Web API 5 there was an `HttpResponseException` (as pointed out by [Hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41472541)) but it's been removed from Core and there's no middleware to handle it.

I think this change is due to .NET Core - where ASP.NET tries to do everything out of the box, ASP.NET Core only does what you specifically tell it to (which is a big part of why it's so much quicker and portable).

I can't find a an existing library that does this, so I've written it myself. First we need a custom exception to check for:

```
public class StatusCodeException : Exception
{
    public StatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then we need a `RequestDelegate` handler that checks for the new exception and converts it to the HTTP response status code:

```
public class StatusCodeExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate request;

    public StatusCodeExceptionHandler(RequestDelegate pipeline)
    {
        this.request = pipeline;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context) => this.InvokeAsync(context); // Stops VS from nagging about async method without ...Async suffix.

    async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.request(context);
        }
        catch (StatusCodeException exception)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode;
            context.Response.Headers.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Then we register this middleware in our `Startup.Configure`:

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseMiddleware<StatusCodeExceptionHandler>();
```

Finally actions can throw the HTTP status code exception, while still returning an explicit type that can easily be unit tested without conversion from `IActionResult`:

```
public Thing Get(int id) {
    Thing thing = GetThingFromDB();

    if (thing == null)
        throw new StatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    return thing;
}
```

This keeps the explicit types for the return values and allows easy distinction between successful empty results (`return null;`) and an error because something can't be found (I think of it like throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`).

While this is a solution to the problem it still doesn't really answer my question - the designers of the Web API build support for explicit types with the expectation that they would be used, added specific handling for  `return null;` so that it would produce a 204 rather than a 200, and then didn't add any way to deal with 404? It seems like a lot of work to add something so basic.

Comment: I think that if the route-resource is valid, but doesn't return anything, the proper response should be 204(No Content)....if the route doesn't exist should return a 404 response(not found)...makes sense, right?

Comment: @Hackerman I suspect that might well be an option, but plenty of client side APIs generalise (1xx on it... 2xx ok, 3xx go here, 4xx you got it wrong, 5xx we got it wrong) - 2xx implies that all is OK, when actually the user requested a resource that isn't there (like the example in my question, the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) considers 204 as OK to continue). I suppose 204 could mean right resource path, wrong resource ID, but that not been my understanding. Any citation on that as the desired pattern?

Comment: Take a look at this article http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/ ...I think that the flow chart for status codes 2xx/3xx explains it very well...you can look at the others too :)\

Comment: @Hackerman That still points to 404 being correct in this context.

Comment: Nope...when they say `Does the resource even exist`, they are meaning the http resource, not the content of that response...for example the request to your api endpoint is a good one and I was able to reach it, yes, then you have a 2XX response...when we talk about a `restful` api, we talk about http resources, like a more natural htpp way..so if one user was able to hit your api endpoint then, an http response 404 doesn't make sense..but if the server response is an empty one, then the proper response should be 204, like, yeah, you hit the right endpoint but I have an empty answer right now.

Comment: @Hackerman I'm really not sure on that - it seems like trying to convey information about the API in the API. If we're doing that shouldn't we also implement 405 (rather than 404) for valid controllers without the requested action and so on? In REST the thing being returned is the resource, not the API itself. I think that's why the convention is for names to be plural (rather than singular like they'd be in a DB) - `api/things/5` is the resource that expects to be a single _thing_.

Comment: Http resources, valid http resources....remember that REST doesn't cares about the logic behind it....I miss sometimes that SO doesn't haves a board where you can write or draw things xD...

Comment: @Hackerman yes, that's kind of why I think `api/missing` and `api/valid/missing` should both return a 404, not 404 for the former and 204 for the latter.

Comment: If you have defined a valid route in your application for `api/valid/{$id}` for example, and you try to hit that endpoint with `api/valid/21` you have a `2xx` response; it doesn't matter if that id with the value of `21` exist or not in your database or if produces a content result or not, the resource exist(your http resource api endpoint)...if 21 produces a result then you have a 200 with for example a json result...if not and returns an empty result, then a 204...Is a little bit hard to understand, it took me a while when I start with this too :)

Comment: @Hackerman but isn't that embedding information about the REST service in those codes - whether the route is valid with a missing ID, or the controller valid without an implementation for the HTTP verb, or the route to the action invalid itself, or even the wrong type (`api/valid/abc` when ID is an `int` will return a 404) - isn't that trying to expose details of the implementation of the service?

Comment: Let's do the opposite...show me on which case you should return a `204` status code?

Comment: @Hackerman POST JSON thing to `api/things/5` hits `public void Post` or `public async Task PostAsync` and it successfully applies the changes with nothing to report but success. The MVC Core designers have added `HttpNoContentOutputFormatter` to force that to return 204 rather than 200.

Comment: And if `5` is invalid or doesn't exist...or the `thing` with the `id` is marked with a soft delete on the parent table....then based on what your previous comments in that case it should returns a `404` status code?

Comment: @Hackerman That would vary by the API - POST can carry out upsert style actions, but if you wanted strict POST updates and PUT additions then yeah, a missing ID would be 404 while a successful update would be a 204.

Comment: "_I'll update this answer with more detail once I've implemented it._" Getting close to implemented? /ducks and runs `;^D` Interested in a revisit, though, honestly. What about a `POST`? (not rocket science, but it'd be nice to have in one place)

Comment: `result ?? NotFound()` will not work since the expression will try to take the type of `result` and not an `ActionResult<T>`.

Answer (score 18):

You can actually use `IActionResult` or `Task<IActionResult>` instead of `Thing` or `Task<Thing>` or even `Task<IEnumerable<Thing>>`. If you have an API that returns **JSON** then you can simply do the following:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ThingsController : Controller
{
    // GET api/things
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
    }

    // GET api/things/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        var thingFromDB = await GetThingFromDBAsync();
        if (thingFromDB == null)
            return NotFound();

        // Process thingFromDB, blah blah blah
        return Ok(thing); // This will be JSON by default
    }

    // POST api/things
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Thing thing)
    {
    }
}
```

**Update**

It seems as though the concern is that being *explicit* in the return of an API is somehow helpful, while it is possible to be *explicit* it is in fact not very useful. If you're writing unit tests that exercise the request / response pipeline you are typically going to verify the raw return (which would most likely be *JSON*, i.e.; a string in **C#**). You could simply take the returned string and convert it back to the strongly typed equivalent for comparisons using `Assert`.

This seems to be the only shortcoming with using `IActionResult` or `Task<IActionResult>`. If you really, really want to be explicit and still want to set the status code there are several ways to do this - but it is frowned upon as the framework already has a built-in mechanism for this, i.e.; using the `IActionResult` returning method wrappers in the `Controller` class. You could write some [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware) to handle this however you'd like, however.

Finally, I would like to point out that if an API call returns `null` according to **W3** a status code of *204* is actually accurate. Why on earth would you want a *404*?

**204**

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

I think the first sentence of the second paragraph says it best, "If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent". This is the case with an API. As compared to a **404**:

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No
>   indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
>   permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server
>   knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old
>   resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
>   This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to
>   reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other
>   response is applicable.

The primary difference being one is more applicable for an API and the other for the document view, i.e.; the page displayed.

Comment: Hi David, cheers. I realise that I can switch to return `IActionResult` - _but if this is the answer why does the ASP.NET Core API Controller support implicit type conversions at all if IActionResult is really required?_

Comment: If you really think about it, an API that claims to return a `Thing` that actually returns `null` is actually the non-body 204. If you want to return something that is more flexible the supported framework approach is to use `IActionResult`. It shouldn't be the framework's responsibility to assume anything, especially 404. But again, you have the ability to do it this way. As an alternative you could add custom middleware to set the `Response.StatusCode` if you'd like instead, but why go through the trouble?

Comment: There already is `HttpNoContentOutputFormatter` middleware ensuring that `null` gets a 204 rather than a 200. I don't want the framework to assume anything - I don't really want to override their default behaviour without understanding exactly why they did it that way. It seems that `public void Post` totally _should_ return a 204 if successful, but `public Anything Get(id)` shouldn't return a success code for a failed action. I feel it's something I'm missing about the intended best practice.

Comment: This uses `Json` to return the `IActionResult` - that works but hard codes the serialiser. Really you want to be able to change the serializer (say to XML) globally without changing every method. Best practice appears to be to use `return Ok(thing);`

Comment: Cheers :-) This appears to be the proposed practice (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4311#issuecomment-271052290) but if it is then my point from the first comment still stands. I've +1 but someone else has silently downvoted (which is helpful).

Comment: @Keith, my answer is the answer for this question. The first comment you're referring to is technically a separate question than this one. Are you more curious about testing now or what?

Comment: Cheers David, but it isn't - that comment is a direct quote from my question. Also from my question _I am not looking for return `NotFound();` as an answer - these only work with `IActionResult` ... that would appear to make explicit return types pointless_ That's what I'm really asking, not "How do I use `NotFound()`" but "How should I return 404 _with explicit typing_" - your answer appears to be "don't use explicit typing", but if it is then it's missing the critical detail as to _why explicit typing is the default (or even supported at all)_

Comment: Cheers for the update :-) That's why I thought they added [`HttpNoContentOutputFormatter`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Formatters/HttpNoContentOutputFormatter.cs) - 204 is correct when no change should be seen in the client's view, it's perfect for anything that returns `void` or `Task` (like most POST actions). However, for `api/things/5` - there is a clear change for the client and they should see some kind of not found message.

Comment: We've been talking about GET `api/things/5` returning a 404 if not found. What about POST `api/things/5` - if that succeeds it should return a 204 (which is what `public void Post` or `public async Task PostAsync` does), but if it failed to update because there is no thing 5 then shouldn't it return a 404 too? Surely it shouldn't return a success status when it's failed?

Comment: This should be the right answer...and about the status codes, there are different implementations(some uses one code, some uses another) based on what you want to accomplish and how...if you want to use a `404` on some cases and as long as your api is well documented, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This shouldn't be the right answer. If you want to /get/{id} and there is no element of that id on the server, a 404 - not found is the correct answer to that. And regarding being explicitly typed - the type information of the method is actually used in tools like swagger who rely on the controllers declaration to be able to generate the correct swagger file. So IActionResult is missing a lot information in that case.

Comment: Good thing this wasn't accepted as the right answer. Thanks for commenting. :)

Answer (score 5):

In order to accomplish something like that(still, I think that the best approach should be using `IActionResult`), you can follow, where you can `throw` an `HttpResponseException` if your `Thing` is `null`:

```
// GET api/things/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<Thing> GetAsync(int id)
{
    Thing thingFromDB = await GetThingFromDBAsync();
    if(thingFromDB == null){
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); // This returns HTTP 404
    }
    // Process thingFromDB, blah blah blah
    return thing;
}
```

Comment: Cheers (+1) - I think this is a step in the right direction, but (on testing) `HttpResponseException` and the middleware to handle it don't appear to be in .NET Core 1.1. The next question is: should I roll my own middleware or is there an existing (ideally MS) package that already does this?

Comment: It looks like this was the way to do this in ASP.NET Web API 5, but it's been dropped in Core, which makes sense given's Core's manual approach. In most of the cases where Core has dropped a default ASP behaviour there's a new optional middleware that you can add in `Startup.Configure`, but there doesn't appear to be one here. In lieu of that it doesn't appear to be too difficult to write one from scratch.

Comment: Ok, I've fleshed out an answer based on this that does work, but still doesn't answer the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41484262/905

Answer (score 5):

From ASP.NET Core 7, a action controller can return a HttpResults type. Then you can :

```cs
public async Task<Results<Ok<Product>, NotFound>> GetAsync(int id)
{
    Thing thingFromDB = await GetThingFromDBAsync();
    if(thingFromDB == null)
        return TypedResults.NotFound();

    ...
    return TypedResults.Ok(thingFromDB);
}
```

I love this syntax, because it's explicitly indicate that return the API. But actually, metadata aren't correctly inferred and OpenApi schema generator (like Swashbuckle) don't generate the expected schema. You can see more detail from this Github ticket :
[TypedResults metadata are not inferred for API Controllers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44988)

While waiting for a resolution, I do a operation filter to generate OpenApi response from HttpResults type and I wrapped it in a NuGet package :
[Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter)

You can add the package :

```bash
dotnet add package Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter
```

So you can register the filter :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    ...
    options.OperationFilter<Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter.HttpResultsOperationFilter>();
});
```

If you prefer, you can just copy/paste the filter file from the package repository :
[HttpResultsOperationFilter.cs](https://github.com/vernou/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter/blob/main/src/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter/HttpResultsOperationFilter.cs)

Answer (score 2):

I too looked high and low for an answer to what to do about strongly typed responses when I wanted to return an 400 response for bad data sent into the request.  My project is in ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET5.0). The solution I found was basically set the status code and return [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) version of the object. Here is your example with the change to set the status code to 404 and return the default object when the db object is null.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ThingsController : Controller
{
    // GET api/things
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Thing>> GetAsync()
    {
        //...
    }

    // GET api/things/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<Thing> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        Thing thingFromDB = await GetThingFromDBAsync();
        if(thingFromDB == null)
        {
            this.Response.StatusCode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return default(Thing);
        }
        
        // Process thingFromDB, blah blah blah
        return thing;
    }

    // POST api/things
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]Thing thing)
    {
        //..
    }

    //... and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core 3.1 introduced [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters).

> Filters in ASP.NET Core allow code to run before or after specific stages in the request processing pipeline.

You can define a result filter that transform null ok result to not found result :

```cs
public class NullAsNotFoundResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    { }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if(context.Result is ObjectResult result && result.Value == null)
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to add the filter in the MVC pipeline  :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers(o => o.Filters.Add<NullAsNotFoundResultFilter>());
```

Answer (score -3):

Had another problem with same behavior - all methods return 404. The problem was in missing code block

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```