# How to handle FileResponse return type of Nswag methods

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, nswag

I am using Nswag to generate client library to consume an API created from .NET Core Application.
Currently I am using actions that returns `IActionResult` to benefit from methods such as `return NotFound();` and `return Ok(objectValue);`
If the return type is `IActionresult` generated Csharp Client methods from Nswag have return type of `FileResponse`.

If I change return type to a certain class then the same return type is returned from the generated methods. This will prevent to use the benefits that I mentioned before.

Usually the return type is from a known return type and never return an anonymous type.

I have managed to get the response from reading the `Stream` from `FileResponse` and converted it to an object with a generic method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);` but this seems to be extra work needed to be done.

Is there anything I am missing to handle `FileResponse` return type? Is it better to change from `IActionResult` to a known object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by changing actions to return `ActionResult<ObjectType>` instead of `IActionResult`. For more detail look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484262/4699575) answer.

Answer (score 0):

NSwag client generator requires additional annotations to generate accurate client code. [`FileResponse` is returned for `IActionResult`](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/85ae862fd6d68173a201a79e0ad06e0be2ec5de1/src/NSwag.Generation/OpenApiSchemaGenerator.cs#L93) - as you stated. If action returns more codes then `ProducesResponseType` helps.

Example using `IActionResult` (string is returned):

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[HttpPost("foo")]
public IActionResult FooAction([FromBody] string param)
```

Example using `ActionResult<>`:

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[HttpPost("foo")]
public ActionResult<string> FooAction([FromBody] string param)
```

Need to know that ASP .NET Core uses `ProblemDetails` (it's configurable) for error codes generated using build-in parameterless methods. If those methods are called with parameter, then `ProducesResponseType` will require to add type - without it wrong code will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Change the return type (e.g.: Instead of `IActionResult` use `FileStreamResult`)
- Use the below code to get the file in SwaggerUI:

  ```
  public async Task<Stream> GetTemplateAttachmentAsync(string fileName) 
  {
       //code here to Get the file from AzureBlob or storage 
  }

  // calling method 
  var content = GetAsync(fileName, cancellationToken);
  return File(content.Stream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
  ```