# IEnumerable - How to manage NotFound error

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I am trying to find a way to return a custom error message when the IEnumerable returns a null object or an empty array

```
    [HttpGet("All/{questionId}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    // [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AnswerDto>> GetAnswers(string questionId)
    {
        var answers = await _context.Answers
            .Where(q => q.QuestionId == questionId)
            .ToListAsync();

        // something like this: if (!answers.Any()) return NotFound(new ApiResponse(404), "There are no answers for this question");

        var answersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IReadOnlyList<AnswerDto>>(answers);
        return answersToReturn;
    }
```

in the ApiResponse class I have:

```
private string GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode(int statusCode)
{
    return statusCode switch
    {
        . . .
        404 => "No item found",
        . . .
    };
}
```

Any help on this please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a 404 from an explicitly typed ASP.NET Core API controller (not IActionResult)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464540/returning-a-404-from-an-explicitly-typed-asp-net-core-api-controller-not-iactio)

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-5.0#access-the-exception and https://www.infoworld.com/article/3545304/how-to-handle-404-errors-in-aspnet-core-mvc.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: I need a case where IEnumerable is involved, as suggested in the question.

Comment: @Sami-L I would highly recommend to read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types) throughoutly to better understand when to use which return type.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [controller action return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iactionresult-type).

`ActionResult` helps in returning HTTP status codes, and will produce a Json result, with the appropriate HTTP status code.

I have tweaked your code a bit to acommodate for it -

```
[HttpGet("All/{questionId}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    // [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult<IEnumerable<AnswerDto>>> GetAnswers(string questionId)
    {
        var answers = await _context.Answers
            .Where(q => q.QuestionId == questionId)
            .ToListAsync();

        if (!answers.Any()) return NotFound("There are no answers for this question");

        var answersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IReadOnlyList<AnswerDto>>(answers);
        return Ok(answersToReturn)
```

Comment: The returned type is not compatible.

Comment: @Sami-L I think you have to inherit from ControllerBase, but you can also  write something like `return new OkObjectResult(answersToReturn);`
and `return new NotFoundObjectResult("There are no answers for this question");`

Comment: @moozywu OkObjectResult cannot be used for this returned type.

Comment: @Sami-L Why not?

Comment: @moozywu what is the returned type of this method ?

Comment: @Sami-L If you change it to `Task<IActionResult<IEnumerable<AnswerDto>>>` there should be no problem, the response is the same same and compiler lets you to handle those 404 responses.

Comment: @moozywu IActionResult is non generic and cannot be used with IEnumerable.

Comment: @Sami-L Oh sorry, I meant just `ActionResult`, which is. But you can also use just plain `Task<IActionResult>` and yes it does.

Comment: @moozywu yes IEnumerable can be wrapped by ActionResult to give a Generic.IReadOnlyList which can be returned using  new OkObjectResult(answersToReturn);  please edit your answer so I can approve it.

Comment: @Sami-L it goes to tejas-panerkar, I was just curious if there is technical reason not to use ActionResult or IActionResult :)

Comment: Thank you for your honesty. but It didn't work because he suggested using IActionResult and return Ok(answersToReturn).