# Recommended way to handle exceptions in ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

Our team is new to ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC development. We are having database CRUD application which is fully asynchronous and both controller and view are created through MVC6 only i.e. there is no WebApi or any client-side platform like Angular. All layers are developed through MVC6.

Now the question is what is the best way to implement exception handling in ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC project? Should we use the separate code for development and production environment? Do we need to use middleware? or Action filter (like we had in MVC 5) is good enough?

I need it for core 2.0, not 1.1. If you know any link which shows correct code to implement middleware for exception handling in Core 2.0 MVC application, please send that.

Comment: First of all, there is no such thing as MVC6, it's just ASP.Net MVC Core. Secondly, this question is too broad, opinion based and asking for external resources, all reasons that make it off topic here.

Comment: The options are the same - a lot. Action filters were *not* the best way in MVC 6, they were *a* way to handle exceptions that had somehow escaped the actions. Some errors can be handled by a local exception handling block, some can't. If you use database transactions, you can retry an action if a deadlock occurs. If you use optimistic concurrency, you may have to check the modified values *first* and notify the user if the code can't resolve what to do

Comment: "Best" and "good enough" are both very subjective terms and depend on many things specific to your circumstances, which are not covered here in any great detail. Often a combination of approaches is suitable to cover all possibilities. One thing I will say though: You asked " Should we use separate code for development and production environment?". IMO absolutely not, because this screws up your deployment pipeline. Different _config_, yes. Different loosely-coupled external components for handling certain things, potentially yes. But a different codebase within the app is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UseExceptionHandler` middleware in `Startup.cs`'s `Configure()`:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

This will execute the route for `/Error` every time you throw an exception.

Of course, you'll need to add an `ErrorController` similar to this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

More information [at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling).

For information on logging exception details check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068386/1678053).

Comment: thanks for your answer. is this approach correct way to implement in core 2.0 also? I heard there are some changes in code? this link shows code for core 1.1, not 2.0. Am I correct?

Comment: can you please send link which has correct code applicable for core 2.0 MVC?

Comment: @Sunil Just because something was introduced in 1.1 doesn't mean it won't work in 2.0. This works and if I'm not wrong is also part of some of the default templates.

Comment: can you please send link which has correct code applicable for core 2.0 MVC?

Comment: @Sunil This is the right code. You don't seem to have tried this. Please don't waste people's time here.  If you're getting an error with this mention it.