# Doesn't ASP.NET Core have an InternalServerError()?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` base class doesn't have an equivalent of `BadRequest()`, `Ok()`, `NoContent()`, etc. for returning HTTP 500 status codes.

Why can't we do?

```cs
try{
  oops();
}
catch(Exception ex){
  //some handling
  return InternalServerError(ex);
}
```

I know can do `return StatusCode(500);`, but we are trying to be more consistent with our HTTP codes and would like to know if there is something more consistent with `Ok()` for returning a 500 code?

Comment: That is the exact same thing. 500 = internal server error. You could always create a quick extension method if you wanted to.

Comment: You could always set the response code manually. `Response.StatusCode = 500;`

Comment: Related post - [How to return HTTP 500 from ASP.NET Core RC2 Web Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37793418/465053)

Answer (score 66):

ASP.NET Core 2.x doesn't have InternalServerError method. Instead you can include the following library.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

And then use the following code.

```
return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
```

Or if you want to add the exception along with the response, try the following code

```
var result = StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, exception);
return result;
```

Comment: If for some reason you need to keep api backward compatible with the 'InternalServerError' you could use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim but the effort of adding the package is more than refactoring your code to the one Foyzul posted.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim

Comment: I don't know if it was the case at the time of the original answer, but the ControllerBase class now has a StatusCode method that returns a StatusCodeResult. So the code can now be:

`return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);`

Answer (score 13):

If just like me you didn't understand where the **StatusCode** method is coming from in Karim's answer, this code will work just as well:

```
var errorObjectResult = new ObjectResult(exceptionMessage);
errorObjectResult.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
                
return errorObjectResult;
```